# Encountering Null value while loading record set into the array in Word VBA, throws Invalid use of Null (using ADODB connection with EXCEL)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, ms-word, ado

Most important thing is that the code is written in Word VBA Editor and it's lunched from Word .docm file.

From this Word .docm file I'm connecting into the Excel file (using ADODB connection), which serves as a client database, and I'm reading whole sheet from that file (sheet name = "data") into a dynamic array which will be searched later.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UseADOSelect()

Dim connection As New ADODB.connection
Dim recSet As New ADODB.Recordset    'All the results of the query are placed in a record set;
Dim exclApp As Excel.Application
Dim exclWorkbk As Excel.Workbook
Dim mySheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Dim cntCntrl As ContentControl
Dim strPESELfromWord As String
Dim strQuery As String
Dim intWiersz As Integer
Dim intRemainder As Integer
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim arraySize As Long       'previously was integer =  -32,768 to 32,767
Dim strSexDigit As String
Dim strArray() As String    'Dim strArray() As Long    'Dim strArray() As String
Dim i As Long

Set wordDoc = Word.ActiveDocument
Debug.Print wordDoc

'Set mySheet = exclApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sample")
'Debug.Print mySheet.Name

strPESELfromWord = Trim(Selection.Text)
Debug.Print strPESELfromWord
Word.Application.Visible = True

strSexDigit = Mid(strPESELfromWord, 10, 1)      'Extract 10th digit from PESEL number
Debug.Print strSexDigit
intRemainder = strSexDigit Mod 2
Debug.Print intRemainder

connection.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = X:\Roesler\Excel\FW 1\custdb.xlsm;" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";"                 'now it works
                                                              
'strQuery = "SELECT * From [Simple$]"   '[Simple$] is the table name; in this case it's the sheet name;
strQuery = "SELECT * From [data$]"     '[data$]   is the table name; in this case it's the sheet name;
```

When the record set is read from the Excel file I need to write it into VBA array.

The problem I'm encountering is that: when I'm looping through the values in the record set, while loading this record set into the array in Word VBA Editor, **Run-time error 94 - Invalid use of Null pops up when the first Null value is drawn from the record set into the array.**

```
'recSet.Open strQuery, connection
recSet.Open strQuery, connection, adOpenStatic        ' Or specify adOpenStatic in the Open method directly.
Debug.Print " RecordCount = " & recSet.RecordCount             'https://www.geeksengine.com/article/recordcount-ado-recordset-vba.html
Debug.Print recSet.EOF      'Returns a value that indicates whether the current record position is after the last record in a Recordset object.
                            'At the moment the value is "False".
Debug.Print recSet.BOF      'The BOF property returns a Boolean value that indicates if the current position in a Recordset object is just before the first record.
                            'If True, you are at BOF. If False, you are at or beyond the first record, but still inside the Recordset.
                            
If recSet.BOF = True Then
   recSet.MoveFirst
End If
                            
'recSet.Open strQuery, connection
'recSet.CursorType = adOpenStatic
Debug.Print " RecordCount = " & recSet.RecordCount             'https://www.geeksengine.com/article/recordcount-ado-recordset-vba.html

arraySize = recSet.RecordCount   'I wanted to assign total number of records to arraySize variable to use it later in ReDim statement.
Debug.Print arraySize

ReDim strArray(1 To arraySize)
For i = 1 To arraySize
   strArray(i) = recSet(i)    'Here the code crashes when the first Null value is encountered, during loading data into the array.
Next i


intRow = 2



'  For Each cntCntrl In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
'    If cntCntrl.Title = "02KlientPelneImie" Then cntCntrl.Range.Text = objExcel.Sheets("data").Cells(intWiersz, 4)
'    If cntCntrl.Title = "02KlientNrDowodu" Then cntCntrl.Range.Text = objExcel.Sheets("data").Cells(intWiersz, 9)
'  Next
```

What am I suppose to do with this.
There are empty cells in the Excel sheet I'm connecting to via ADODB connection with EXCEL. Nothing I can do about it.

**How can I load a worksheet into a record set and later this record set into an array in Word VBA, while I have Null values inside??**

[image]

Comment: If you declare `strArray()` without a type that should work.  Or `strArray(i) = recSet(i) & ""` to coerce the null to an empty string.

Comment: I'd like to use this second method ```strArray(i) = recSet(i) & ""```, as I imagine, it lets me keep the string data type that I've set up for my array contents. But can you guide me where in my macro should I place it?

Comment: And is ```i``` a new variable I should declare? Eventually I'll need two-dimensional array as I have data in many columns in that file and I'll need to preserve the source layout of my data after loading them into the array.

Comment: That line just replaces the line which was causing the error.  Not sure what you're asking about declaring `i` - it's already in your code...