# How to load data from Excel sheet into the two-dimensional array using record set from ADODB connection with EXCEL file?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, ms-word, ado

My goal is to load data from a record set (ADODB connection with EXCEL file) into the two-dimensional array I need for my Word VBA macro.

I want to stress that the code is written in Word VBA Editor and it's lunched from Word .docm file. The data I'm talking about is imported into this macro via ADODB connection with an EXCEL file, that's used as a clients database.

The confusion I feel is because I don't understand if the record set, that was created with ADODB connection with EXCEL file, is one or two-dimensional. I ask this because after I have this record set **I need to load it into two-dimensional array, and I don't really know how to do this.**

The data I grab from Excel file via ADODB connection with source EXCEL file looks like this:

[image: how far to the right the columns are imported into the record set??]

So if the data in the record set are one dimensional, how would I fit it into the two dimensional array, to preserve the way they are arranged (graphically) in the spreadsheet???

Currently, I have all the time the same source row of data imported into every other row in the array. Therefore, I have first row of my source data in every row of the array and It's not what I need.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The code looks like this:

```
Sub UseADOSelect_02()

Dim connection As New ADODB.connection
Dim recSet As New ADODB.Recordset    'All the results of the query are placed in a record set;

Dim exclApp As Excel.Application     'This code is written and lunched from Word VBA Editor
Dim exclWorkbk As Excel.Workbook
Dim mySheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Dim cntCntrl As ContentControl
Dim strPESELfromWord As String
Dim strQuery1 As String
Dim strQuery2 As String
Dim intWiersz As Integer
Dim intRemainder As Integer
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim arraySize As Long       'previously was integer =  -32,768 to 32,767

Dim strSexDigit, y As String
Dim strArray() As String    'Dim strArray() As Long    'Dim strArray() As String    'We don't specify the size of dynamic array when we declare it;
Dim i, j, k As Long         '"k" is the recStet number


'Set exclApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")   'When no Excel Workbook is open an error 429 will be returned.
'Debug.Print exclApp

Set wordDoc = Word.ActiveDocument
Debug.Print wordDoc

'Set mySheet = exclApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
'Debug.Print mySheet.Name

'Set mySheet = exclApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sample")
'Debug.Print mySheet.Name

strPESELfromWord = Trim(Selection.Text)
Debug.Print strPESELfromWord
Word.Application.Visible = True

strSexDigit = Mid(strPESELfromWord, 10, 1)      'Extract 10th digit from PESEL number
Debug.Print strSexDigit
intRemainder = strSexDigit Mod 2
Debug.Print intRemainder

connection.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = X:\Roesler\Excel\FW 1\custdb.xlsm;" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";"                 'now it works
                                


'strQuery1 = "SELECT * From [Simple$]"   '[Simple$] is the table name; in this case it's the sheet name;
strQuery1 = "SELECT * From [data$]"     '[data$]   is the table name; in this case it's the sheet name;
strQuery2 = "SELECT * From [data$] WHERE pesel <> ''"      'col B = pesel; col C = data_urzodzenia; col D = imie_nazwisko
'recSet.Open strQuery1, connection
recSet.Open strQuery2, connection, adOpenStatic        ' Or specify adOpenStatic in the Open method directly.
Debug.Print " RecordCount = " & recSet.RecordCount             'https://www.geeksengine.com/article/recordcount-ado-recordset-vba.html
Debug.Print "EOF value = " & recSet.EOF
                            'Returns a value that indicates whether the current record position is after the last record in a Recordset object.
                            'At the moment the value is "False".
Debug.Print "BOF value = " & recSet.BOF
                            'The BOF property returns a Boolean value that indicates if the current position in a Recordset object is just before the first record.
                            'If True, you are at BOF. If False, you are at or beyond the first record, but still inside the Recordset.
                            
If recSet.BOF = True Then
   recSet.MoveFirst
End If
                            
'recSet.Open strQuery, connection
'recSet.CursorType = adOpenStatic
Debug.Print " RecordCount = " & recSet.RecordCount             'https://www.geeksengine.com/article/recordcount-ado-recordset-vba.html

arraySize = recSet.RecordCount   'I wanted to assign total number of records to arraySize variable to use it later in ReDim statement.
Debug.Print "arraySize is = " & arraySize

k = 0
ReDim strArray(0 To arraySize - 1, 0 To 71 - 1)
For i = 0 To arraySize          '1st question - Does "i" denote the first "recSet" number??           '"i" is now 181
  For j = LBound(strArray, 2) To UBound(strArray, 2)    '2nd question - Does "i" denote "strArray's" row??
     'k = 0                                              '3rd question - Does "j" from line above denote "strArray's" column??
     For k = 0 To 71 - 1
          strArray(i, j) = recSet(k + 1) & ""
         'strArray(i) = recSet(i) & ""      'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63814028/encountering-null-value-while-loading-record-set-into-the-array-in-word-vba-thr
         'i = i + 1
          j = j + 1
     Next k
  Next j
Next i


intRow = 2



'  For Each cntCntrl In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
'    If cntCntrl.Title = "02KlientPelneImie" Then cntCntrl.Range.Text = objExcel.Sheets("data").Cells(intWiersz, 4)
'    If cntCntrl.Title = "02KlientNrDowodu" Then cntCntrl.Range.Text = objExcel.Sheets("data").Cells(intWiersz, 9)
'  Next

connection.Close
End Sub
```

I expect mistake is somewhere here:

```
arraySize = recSet.RecordCount   'I wanted to assign total number of records to arraySize variable to use it later in ReDim statement.
Debug.Print "arraySize is = " & arraySize

k = 0
ReDim strArray(0 To arraySize - 1, 0 To 71 - 1)
For i = 0 To arraySize          '1st question - Does "i" denote the first "recSet" number??           '"i" is now 181
  For j = LBound(strArray, 2) To UBound(strArray, 2)    '2nd question - Does "i" denote "strArray's" row??
     'k = 0                                              '3rd question - Does "j" from line above denote "strArray's" column??
     For k = 0 To 71 - 1
          strArray(i, j) = recSet(k + 1) & ""
         'strArray(i) = recSet(i) & ""      'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63814028/encountering-null-value-while-loading-record-set-into-the-array-in-word-vba-thr
         'i = i + 1
          j = j + 1
     Next k
  Next j
Next i
```

Immediate window:

[image]

Comment: Did you know that ADO has a method called `GetRows` which will create an array directly from your recordset?  Eg see http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_ado_load_array.html

Comment: To answer your question though - a recordset is not an array but a set of record objects. 
 However, it has "rows" (records) and "columns" (fields) so you could think of it as a 2D table of data.  Your array only has the first record because you never call `recSet.MoveNext` to advance the cursor to the next record.

Comment: @ Tim Williams  Do you suggest I should use ```GetRows``` method instead of this ```For...Next``` loop I'm using to load the data into my Word VBA Array?

Comment: I found it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getrows-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver15   Is this the right help page? Because it refers to MS SQL Server.

Comment: @TimWilliams From this link you shared   http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_ado_load_array.html   in the first comment, there is a line in the end and variable in this procedure ```txtBooks.Text = txt   'Display the results.``` and I don't know what is ```txtBooks``` variable and how to declare it, as what type??

Comment: `values = rs.GetRows` is really the only line I was pointing you to there.  I don't know what you intend to do with the resulting array.